# Circular view path [greeting]

Tags: spring

I am using `spring-boot-starter-paren: 2.3.2.RELEASE`.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.sweater;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(name="name",
                                         required=false,
                                         defaultValue="World") String name,
                           Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("name", name);
        return "greeting";
    }
}
```

Stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/wtS2ubus

> Problem: javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [greeting]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/greeting] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)

How can I debug this?

Comment: How did you get on with the below answer, Trts?

Comment: Change `return "greeting"` to something else, eg: `return "Hello World";`

Answer (score 0):

The `circular path exception` happens due to default ViewResolvers in spring. If your `@GetMapping` on path = 'path' returns a value which is also defined as a view in your project (html or equivalent, i.e path.html) then this error occurs.

As stated in the below source:

> By default, the Spring MVC framework applies the InternalResourceView class as the view resolver. As a result, if the @GetMapping value is the same as the view, the request will fail with the Circular View path will occur.
>
> One possible solution would be to rename the view and change the return value in the controller method.
>
> If we don't want to rename the view and change the return value in the controller method, then another solution is to choose another view processor for the project.

Source:https://www.baeldung.com/spring-circular-view-path-error

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue it was resolved by changing @Controller to @RestController